# Ошибка при загрузке видео с YouTube с помощью pytube

Tags: python, pytube

Возникает ошибка:

> get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple

Я уже менял версии и менял параметры в файлах.

```py
def download_best_quality_video(link):
    try:
        yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
        best_quality_stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        best_quality_stream.download()
    except Exception as exception:
        print(f"Exception! {exception}")


video_link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKtFo15RgrU&ab_channel=Xdree-Topic'
download_best_quality_video(video_link)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разработчик особо не проверил, видимо, стабильность новой версии. Попробуйте исправить, как сказано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945080/pytube-exceptions-regexmatcherror-get-throttling-function-name-could-not-find

По крайней мере, если не отлавливать ошибку через try - except будет видно, что ошибка в регулярном выражении "RegexError". В принципе на гитхаб - https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1682 - проблема ваша уже есть, просто подождите новой версии пакета, если не хотите сами попытаться исправить, так сказать.

Comment: Тут в комменатриях на гитхаб приложили такой же фикс. https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1678#issuecomment-1603948730

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое